# What are polynomials of degree less than $N$ in $x$?

Tags: definition, linear-algebra

I don't understand what this question is asking me:

> Consider the collection of all [polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) (with complex coefficients) of degree less than $N$ in $x$.

Does this mean the polynomials like $$ Ax^{N-1},\  Bx^{N-2}, \  Cx^{N-3},  \ ...$$ where $A$,$B$,$C$ are complex coefficients? If so, when does this series end and what is its null vector?

Comment: This is not a physics question. Please post questions like this on Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: Tell that to Griffiths

Comment: Finding a problem in a physics book does not make it a physics problem :) Anyway, please do take the advice of other users on this site; we spend a lot of time trying to keep everything tidy and high-quality. Directing math questions to the math site helps everyone direct their questions to the best place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomials of degree less than $N$ with complex coefficients are given by
$$\left \{\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i x^i | a_i \in \mathbb{C}\right \} $$
The important thing is to note that a polynomial does not have negative powers of $x$.
This is as you have rightly stated a vector space (which can be visualised as $\mathbb{C}^{N}$). The null vector is the only polynomial which can be added to every other polynomial without changing this one - I leave that to you.
It surprises me, though, that you were not able to find this by a simple search on google ...

Comment: Shouldn't the series stop at N-1 and not N since it is polynomials of degree less than N?  Also why does it stop at $x^0$?

Comment: @Shrodinger2016 I am sorry for giving the wrong exponent, I was thinking "less or equal than", I will correct that. Expressions with negative exponents in $x$ are usually not called polynomials, thus I would not expect to see them included. Stopping at $i=0$ is simply to have the most general case.

Comment: I still don't understand the null vector. The only null vector for this set would be 0, but there is no way I can get 0 with exponents unless one of my coefficients happens to be 0.

Comment: as $0 \in \mathbb{C}$ it is a valid choice for all $a_i$. So there is no issue with that. @count_to_10 thanks for the flattery, but you really should not downplay your knowledge ;)

Comment: Sanya, please refrain from answering off-topic questions. The question here is clearly a pure math question and as such should have been posted on the math site. I would encourage you *at least* help the asker by directing them to the right site before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that you have the set $S=\{(Ax^{N-1}+Bx^{N-2}+...+F_{n}),\,(A_{1}x^{N-2}+B_{2}x^{N-3}+...+F_{n1})\,,{(polinomyal)},{(polinomyal)},{(polynomial)}....{(F_{nn)}} \}$

The null vector depends on what operation you're using, if you are multiplying this set, the null vector is 1. 
Let $\vec{v}=A_{1}x^{N-2}+B_{2}x^{N-3}+...+F_{n1}$ and you define multiplication as the linear operation, then $\vec{v}*1=\vec{v}$ and technically $1$ is a polynomial of degree less that N, if $ N\epsilon \mathbf{N} $

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE and thanks for your answer :) Any vector space needs to have inverses, so I believe in the multiplication case this would rather be a monoid if my algebra hasn't left me.